# Paginating a table with multiple <tbody> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Let us say I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    ....
    .... 1000s of records like this
</table>
```

Is there a way I can paginate based on `tbody` elements? For instance, I want to display the first 50 records on page 1 and so on. Is there a jQuery plugin that does this already or should I write my own? Any suggestions?

Comment: Using JavaScript for dealing with 1000 elements on the page is _overkill_, why not doing this on server-side?

Comment: I don't know of a specific paginator for that structure. It shouldn't be too hard to write it yourself. The math is easy and jQuery makes selection/showing/hiding trivial. About 3 hours work fully tested.

Comment: http://datatables.net has pagination options.

Comment: @undefined: So if I understand you correctly, even fetching the data and keeping on the client-side (for future rendering) is expensive so you're suggesting that I implement pagination on the server-side and get data to be displaed on the current page?

Comment: just hide all but the first tbody initially, and for each tbody in the table, add a page link that shows that specific tbody and hides the rest on click. jQuery should make that relatively easy. Though, i prefer to do pagination using ajax and the server to prevent sending a lot of data to the user that the user may not use.

Comment: The first fifty `tr` elements, or the first fifty `tbody` elements?

Comment: @DavidThomas: First 50 `tbody` elements. I'm using a `tbody` element to logically group related rows together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legend,

[jQuery Pagination Plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm) - nice find.

Here's a way to use the plugin to do far more closely to what you asked for originally.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $tbodies = $("#myTable tbody");

    // Create pagination element with options from form
    var paginationOpts = {
        callback: pageselectCallback,
        items_per_page: 5,
        num_display_entries: 10,
        num_edge_entries: 2,
        prev_text: "Prev",
        next_text: "Next"
    };

    function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq) {
        //calculate limits of the page in terms of tbody indices
        var limits = {
            start: page_index * paginationOpts.items_per_page,
            end: (page_index + 1) * paginationOpts.items_per_page
        };
        $tbodies.filter(":visible").hide();
        $tbodies.slice(limits.start, limits.end).show();
        // Prevent click eventpropagation
        return false;
    }

    $("#Pagination").pagination($tbodies.length, paginationOpts);
});
```

I'm not saying this is better. For 1000+ tbodies, the HTML may be huge and page transitions may be horribly slow, but this approach could have saved you development time had you not already revised the way the data is served.

May be of use to someone in the future.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdCPs/4/)

Comment: +1 Thank You for your time. For some reason, I cannot access the link? Also, in my approach, I am not constructing the entire HTML at once but rather depending on what page view is being viewed. Also, I agree with your comment though. Its a lack of foresight on my part - I should have just implemented pagination on the server-side. Lesson well learnt :)

Comment: Legend, yes your page will be smaller by serving the data as javascript rather than as fully formed HTML. FWIW, I've corrected the link to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to implement the pagination server side.

As said in the comment, [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) seems to be the best way for you to go.
I might also consider [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)

Note that you have the choose client side or server side pagination with these APIs

Comment: Thank you. My only concern is that these seem to work out-of-the-box for conventional tables (one `tbody` tag with multiple `tr` tags). However, in my use case, I have a custom layout and I'm not understanding how to adapt these plugins for my use case. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: This page seems to answer your question: [http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html). You can override the fnDrawCallback to create a new tbody tag for each group.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working through a light-weight plugin called [jQuery Pagination Plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm).

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Legend/ZdCPs/) if anyone is interested.

HTML:

```
<div id="Pagination" class="pagination"></div>
<br style="clear:both" />
<table id="Searchresult"></table>
```

JS:

```
var members = [
    // Any data array
];

var n = "";
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq) {
    // Get number of elements per pagionation page from form
    var items_per_page = 5;
    var max_elem = Math.min((page_index + 1) * items_per_page, members.length);
    var newcontent = '';

    // Iterate through a selection of the content and build an HTML string
    newcontent = "<table>";
    for (var i = page_index * items_per_page; i < max_elem; i++) {
        newcontent += '<tbody><tr><td>' + members[i][0] + '</td></tr>';
        newcontent += '<tr><td class="state">' + members[i][2] + '</td>';
        newcontent += '<td class="party">' + members[i][3] + '</td></tr></tbody>';
    }
    newcontent += "</table>";

    // Replace old content with new content
    $('#Searchresult').html(newcontent);

    // Prevent click eventpropagation
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create pagination element with options from form
    var opt = {
        callback: pageselectCallback
    };
    opt.items_per_page = 5;
    opt.num_display_entries = 10;
    opt.num_edge_entries = 2;
    opt.prev_text = "Prev";
    opt.next_text = "Next";

    $("#Pagination").pagination(members.length, opt);
});
```