# Add jQuery pagination plugin to table read from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I found this [jQuery Plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm) thanks to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209838/paginating-a-table-with-multiple-tbody-elements) to a post by [BeetRoot-BeetRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142252/beetroot-beetroot). The plugin is exactly what I need and I want to add it to my page but my table is created by obtaining the elements from a db. I tried adding it to the page as the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdCPs/4/) sample but pagination just does not show. The only change I am making to the jsFiddle code is the instead of breaking the pages every tbody element I want it to break it every tr element. Here is the code for the table, any suggestion is welcomed.

```
var columns = ["username", "user_id", "address", "state", "postal_code", "phone", "email"];

var level_classes = {
    "NEW": "new_client",
    "RENEWAL": "renewing_client",
    "CURRENT": "current_client"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("obtainUsers.php", function(data) {
        var $table = $('<table style="width: 100%;">');
        var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
        $table.append($tbody);
        var $tr = null;

        data.forEach(function(user, index) {
            if (index % 4 === 0) {
                $tr = $('<tr>');
                $tbody.append($tr);
            }
            $td = $('<td class="' + level_classes[user.level] + '">');
            columns.forEach(function(col) {
                $td.append(user[col]);
                $td.append($('<br>'));
            });
            $tr.append($td);
        });
        $('.runninglist').append($table);
    });
});
```

Comment: Not all plugins that do the same thing are equal..finding a well documented one is as important as what it does. There are numerous other pagination plugins. You might want to look at others as well and see if the api documents and examples will help you better

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Charlietfl, I do understand that all plugins are not the same, but what I wanted to know if is possible to apple this plugin to my code. I never try doing a plugin before and this I what I am trying to get help for.

Comment: well I don't know where the documentation is for it and that's my point. You most likely can but requires looking through the plugin source and understanding how that code works if there is no documentation

Comment: Oh I am sorry, this is the [page](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#pagination) I am referring.